# Making call to API and having trouble decoding certain characters (Django)

Tags: python, django, json

The JSON data I'm getting back from an API call has a character in it `\x96`

It's causing the following error when I make the API call:

```
'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\x96' in position 56: ordinal not in range(128)
```

This happens occasionally with the API calls -- maybe 5% of the time when there is I guess this unicode data it can't decode. Any idea how to decode these characters?

Here's my code:

```
    start = str(start)
    limit = str(limit) 
    if sort_by:
        url = self.base_url + specific_url + "?q=" + str(query) + "&filters=[[%22category_id%22,[" + category_id + "]]]" + "&start=" + start  + "&limit=" + limit + "&sortby=" + sort_by + "&apikey=" + self.api_key 
    else:
        url = self.base_url + specific_url + "?q=" + str(query) + "&filters=[[%22category_id%22,[" + category_id + "]]]" + "&start=" + start  + "&limit=" + limit + "&apikey=" + self.api_key

    response_json = self.web_fetch(url)
    return simplejson.loads(response_json)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`simplejson.loads` must take a `unicode` object for this to work.

This means that you need to amend the `web_fetch()` function to return a Unicode object, or you can just decode `response_json` as UTF8 if you know that that is its encoding.

```
response_json = response_json.decode('utf-8')
```